# Can an admin create a post on a Facebook page that gets broadcast to all followers?

Tags: facebook

For a company's Facebook page, I would like the director to add a page post *as himself*. However, the post should be broadcast to all the page's followers as if it were published by the page.

Is this possible somehow?

I've looked in Facebook's help pages but am unable to find anything on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually don't think this is possible, unless the director establishes a page for himself and gets all the same followers. I'd just Title the post "Direct message from [Director name here]:" or something.

I've tried to do it before and couldn't find a single solution. I think it should be suggested to the people at Facebook to add this kind of capability :).

Answer (score 0):

cant you go to the page's admin area, and using the "manage admins" option add the director as an admin?

i havent tried this, but i expect once hes an admin, he can make posts as the page, and as another person suggested, you can just have him sign the message with his name

Comment: nope, I already tried this.  It looks like what Admins post on the wall has the same priority as fans' wall posts (i.e. it doesn't get shown in the fans' feed)